# Parallel.For/Foreach threads reuse C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

Is there a way to reuse threads used in consecuent calls of `Parallel.ForEach` loop? I am tring to do because I understand that thread creation can be costly.

Thats what i would like to do:

```
var collection = CreateMyCollection()
var pool = CreateThreadPool()
for(int i =0 ; i<1000 ; i++)
      Parallel.ForEach(pool, collection, (element) => Calculate(element, i))
```

Is it possible?

Note: I cannot parallize the external loop instead (hard dependancy between 'i's')

Comment: I want to say that the threads that the `Parallel` methods use just come from the task pool, so using tasks should essentially be reusing those same threads.

Comment: Wow, I will lookup the documentation for that, do you have a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel.ForEach is part of [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx). By default [TaskSceduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321418.aspx), responsible for queuing work items onto threads, will use ThreadPool.

> An instance of the TaskScheduler class represents a task scheduler. A
>   task scheduler ensures that the work of a task is eventually executed.
>   The default task scheduler is based on the .NET Framework 4 thread
>   pool, which provides work-stealing for load-balancing, thread
>   injection/retirement for maximum throughput, and overall good
>   performance. It should be sufficient for most scenarios. The
>   TaskScheduler class also serves as the extension point for all
>   customizable scheduling logic. This includes mechanisms such as how to
>   schedule a task for execution, and how scheduled tasks should be
>   exposed to debuggers. If you require special functionality, you can
>   create a custom scheduler and enable it for specific tasks or queries.

Comment: Thank you very much